# How can I style the display of an array resulted through var_dump

Tags: php, arrays

I've a code to search files in a directory. I'm using the code `var_dump($search->foundFiles)` to display the results in a webpage, but I can't figure out how to find te correct code for proper display and the the results are URL.

The result of `var_dump($search->foundFiles)` is:

> Array ( [0] => archivednews/2016-01-08 22h30 Zika Virus archived news.html
>   [1] => archivednews/2016-01-07 22h30 Zika Virus archived news.html )

But I would like to have it displayed in a list with clickable links to the found files like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="archivednews/2016-01-05 22h30 Zika Virus archived news.html">2016-01-05 22h30 Zika Virus archived news.html</a></li>
   <li><a href="archivednews/2016-01-04 22h30 Zika Virus archived news.html">2016-01-04 22h30 Zika Virus archived news.html</a></li>
   <li><a href="archivednews/2016-01-08 22h30 Zika Virus archived news.html">2016-01-08 22h30 Zika Virus archived news.html</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the complete code:

```
class searchFileContents{
     var $dir_name = '';//The directory to search
     var $search_phrase = '';//The phrase to search in the file contents
     var $allowed_file_types = array('php','phps');//The file types that are searched
     var $foundFiles;//Files that contain the search phrase will be stored here
     var $myfiles;

  function search($directory, $search_phrase){
    $this->dir_name = $directory;
    $this->search_phrase = $search_phrase;

    $this->myfiles = $this->GetDirContents($this->dir_name);
    $this->foundFiles = array();

    if ( empty($this->search_phrase) ) die('Empty search phrase');
    if ( empty($this->dir_name) ) die('You must select a directory to search');

    foreach ( $this->myfiles as $f ){
        if ( in_array(array_pop(explode ( '.', $f )),  $this->allowed_file_types) ){
            $contents = file_get_contents($f);
            if ( strpos($contents, $this->search_phrase) !== false )
                $this->foundFiles [] = $f;
        }
    }
    return $this->foundFiles;
  }

  function GetDirContents($dir){
   if (!is_dir($dir)){die ("Function GetDirContents: Problem reading : $dir!");}
   if ($root=@opendir($dir)){
       while ($file=readdir($root)){
           if($file=="." || $file==".."){continue;}
           if(is_dir($dir."/".$file)){
               $files=array_merge($files,$this->GetDirContents($dir."/".$file));
           }else{
           $files[]=$dir."/".$file;
           }
       }
   }
   return $files;
  }
}

//Example :

$search = new searchFileContents;
$search->search('E:/htdocs/AccessClass', 'class');
var_dump($search->foundFiles);
```

Comment: `var_dump` has a fixed format. Do `foreach` and `echo` values.

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump` is only used when developing. It's only a helper for debugging.
When the application is done you can't output it to the user.

You can do this to print each value of the array just as the var_dump would do:

```
foreach($search->foundFiles as $ffiles)
    echo "<a href='$ffiles'>$ffiles</a><br>";
```

This would display this:

[2016-01-05 22h30 Zika Virus archived news.html](http://2016-01-05%2022h30%20Zika%20Virus%20archived%20news.html)

[2016-01-04 22h30 Zika Virus archived news.html](http://2016-01-04%2022h30%20Zika%20Virus%20archived%20news.html)

[2016-01-08 22h30 Zika Virus archived news.html](http://2016-01-08%2022h30%20Zika%20Virus%20archived%20news.html)

But the urls from the array aren't real links, so you would have to work it out.

Comment: Thanks, great, it works!! But how can I sort the result list as it seems that all the files are shown in random order?

Comment: They are coming in the same order as in the var_dump. You can use many array functions to sort them in alphabetical order, for example.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no clue how to sort them

Comment: I found it, thanks for all the help: www.zikavirusnet.com

Comment: Researching and trying is the best way to learn any programming language. Don't forget to pick a selected answer.